# How to print bubble sort after this I get printed array not bubble sort

Tags: visual-c++

### How to print bubble sort after this I get  printed array not bubble sort

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void sortzeroandones(int arr[],int n)
{
    int left=0,right=n-1;
    while(left<right)
    {
        while(arr[left]==0 && right>left)
         left++;
         while(arr[right]==1 && right>left)
         right--;
         if(left<right)
         {
            arr[left]==0;
            arr[right]==1;
            left++;
            right--;
         }
    }
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
      int arr[n];
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
     }
     sortzeroandones(arr,n);
    
     
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
     }
     
    
    return 0;
}
```

the given code is given. i want print sorted array but i get only print array and given by user.

how it get correct.

Comment: Show the input you provide, the output you expect for this input, and the output you observe instead.

Comment: Input=   1  5  9  8  2           output of code=    1  5  9  8  2           expected output = 1 2  5  8 9

Comment: `sortzeroandones` expects that all elements of the array are, well, zeros or ones; and wouldn't work correctly otherwise. Your input contains values that are not zeros or ones. The function does not implement bubble sort, as you seem to believe.

Comment: Oh I put wrong value

Comment: Input  0 1 1 0 1 1    my output  = 0  1  1 0  1 1   same as input          original output     0  0  1  1  1 1

Comment: `arr[left]==0;` and `arr[right]==1;` are no-ops. It's a comparison whose result is not used. You probably meant `arr[left]=0;` - an assignment, not a comparison.